# ZipArchive throws error if file is renamed after uploading

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

If I upload a zip file, and rename it, the ZipArchive function throws an ER_NOZIP error when I try to extract it, whereas if I upload and don't rename it will extract with no issues.

Is this a known issue or is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help would be great!

**EDIT for more details:**
The process is this: I can zip up a folder on my host and download it using ZipArchive just fine via PHP in my browser. Then I have a process where I can upload that zip file and unzip it on my host using ZipArchive. This works fine. The problem seems to come when I download something with the same name and Windows gives it a name like "My_file (2).zip".

When I upload this file, that's when I get the NOZIP error. I used the rename() function to change it's name to remove spaces etc so that it becomes "my_file_2.zip" but it still throws an error. It seems as though only the originally named file will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out after a lot of testing back and forth, though it seems obvious now.

It seems that when I was downloading the newly created zip from the script/browser, that the header mime type affected the file randomly (not sure why unaltered zip archives worked, but renamed files didn't still).

Either way, using these headers in the download script seems to have resolved the issue completely:

```
    $finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    $mimeType = finfo_file($finfo, $zipDir);

    header("Cache-Control: private, max-age=120, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // long ago
    header("Content-Type: $mimeType");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($zipDir) . "\"");
    header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($zipDir));
```

Previously the script was using `application/octet-stream` as the mime type, and changing it to use the proper zip mime appears to fix the issue, so even renaming the file etc doesn't cause errors anymore.

Hopefully this will also help others who may run into similar issues.